# angularJs ui-router and the data object

Tags: angularjs

So, when I first moved to ui-router I was using the **data** object to set things like pageTitle and requireLogin:

```
resolve: {

    // Resolve our user
    user: ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        // Get our role
        var user = $rootScope.user;

        // Return our user
        return user;
    }],

    // Resolve our role
    role: ['user', function (user) {

        // Get our role
        var role = user.role;

        // Return our role
        return role;
    }]
},
data: {
    requireLogin: true,
    pageTitle: 'Dashboard'
}
```

in my app.run I would have this:

```
// Apply the state to the rootscope
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```

Then in my index view I would have a partial that would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1>{{ $state.current.data.pageTitle }} <small>{{ $state.current.data.pageSubTitle }}</small></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

all find an dandy, but now I have been given the task of setting dynamic titles based on what role a user belongs to when the visit a page.
Does anyone know how I can tackle that?

Comment: when you get the roles for users?

Comment: I resolve them in the actual route. I have updated the question so you can see